# $t function does not work in lithium email template

Tags: php, email, templates, lithium

I have a email template onecode.mail.php

Which I call from

```
$body = $view->render(
    'template',
    compact('users','oneCode','username'),
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'template'=>'onecode',
        'type' => 'mail',
        'layout' => false
    )
);
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject("Sign in password");
$message->setFrom(array(NOREPLY => 'Sign in password'));
$message->setTo($email);
$message->setBody($body,'text/html');
$mailer->send($message);
```

onecode.mail.php contains

```
<?=$t('Login Email Password')?>
<?=$oneCode?>
```

I get an error while processing this request as:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Function name must be a string in <b>app\resources
\tmp\cache\templates
\template_views_users_onecode.mail_0_1460392715_2266.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br/>
```

Translation works perfect in all the .html.php files but not in the template of .email.php

What should be done? Any suggestions, thanks for the help.

Comment: It means that the value of `$t` is not a function name. Try `echo $t;` in onecode.mail.php to see what it is. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion, did not change the error. I never initialized it when I used in .html.php files, so for .mail.php also I did not initialize it.

It is initialized in one of the lithium libraries \lithium\g11n\Message.php. I tried calling that library 

use \lithium\gmm1\Message;

No help!

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying. I'm not familar with the Lithium library. Perhaps it's due to `'type' => 'mail'` if that's different from your other files. Maybe prepending `<?php extract(Message::aliases()); ?>` to your onecode.mail.php fixes it? (found it [here](http://li3.me/docs/manual/common-tasks/globalization.md)). Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks!!!
By adding these two lines to the template email.php it worked.
use lithium\g11n\Message; extract(Message::aliases());

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following lines in your template:

```
<?php
use lithium\g11n\Message;
extract(Message::aliases());
?>
<?=$t('Login Email Password')?>
```

You should be able to get the translation in your desired language